Is there a canonical smooth structure on tame Fréchet orbit type stratifications?
In finite dimension orbit type stratifications, it is known that the orbit space $M/G$ resulting from an action of a proper Lie Group $G$ on a smooth manifold $M$, satisfying a set of certain properties, is canonically a stratified space with a smooth structure turning the projection $\pi:M\rightarrow M/G$ into a smooth stratified map. I refer here to chapter 4 of Pfl01 for details and the definition of a smooth structure on a stratification.
Much of the theory of orbit type stratification was recently extended to the infinite dimensional tame Fréchet setting in the paper DR19. However, although the conditions under which $M/G$ is a stratified space are established in this paper, along with certain regularity properties extending the finite dimensional case, I could not find a discussion about a smooth structure associated with it. The proof of this fact in the finite dimensional setting Pfl01 does not seem to be directly extendable to the infinite dimensional one.
Does anyone know if an extension of this fact from the finite dimensional case is possible and under what conditions? Thanks
EDIT: Here is the regularity proprety mentioned above for tame Fréchet stratified spaces, I tried to infer from it that a smooth structure exists but failed:
Let $(\mathscr{Y},\Sigma)$ be a stratified space. A pair of strata satisfying $\mathscr{Y}_{\zeta}<\mathscr{Y}_{\sigma}$ is said to be smoothly regular if for all $z\in\mathscr{Y}_{\zeta}$ there exists an open neighborhood $\mathscr{U}$ of $z$ in $\mathscr{Y}$ such that for all $y\in\mathscr{U}\cap \mathscr{Y}_{\sigma}$, there exists an injective and continuous linear map $T_{z}\mathscr{Y}_{\zeta}\rightarrow T_{y}\mathscr{Y}_{\sigma}$.  The space is called smoothly regular if all its strata are pairwise smoothly regular.

As far as I am aware Tobias work on that topic is more or less all there is. I would recommend contacting him directly to see whether he knows of more.

I will let him know of this question, thanks!

I sadly cannot say much more. When we wrote the paper, we did think about the smooth structure but couldn't find a proof that works in infinite dimensions. I believe the proof given by Pflaum works almost without change if the quotient is finite dimensional (e.g. your slices are finite dimensional submanifold). But if that's not the case, you need to understand the space $V / G$ where $V$ is a representation of a compact group $G$ (the stabilizer). Thus, perhaps if you know enough about the representation theory of all possible stabilizers this might work. But in full generality I have no idea

Depending on the applications that you have in mind a more direct approach might work. For example, you can still define an algebra of smooth functions on the quotient to be the invariant functions upstairs. On the other hand, the "smoothly regular" property might be helpful if you want to talk about tangent spaces and vector fields on the quotient.
